# Undefined index error(subject_code and course_code) in php

Tags: php

I am currently working in php. in the below code i got undefined index: subject_code at line 42 and undefined index : course_code at line 24. so anyone help me.
i tried to remove the error but i can't .so anyone help me.

```
        <script language="javascript">
        function changeSelection(value){

           var length = document.getElementById("hai3").options.length;

         if(value == 0){
          for(var i = 1;i<length;i++)
        document.getElementById("hai3").options[i].selected = "selected";

            document.getElementById("hai3").options[0].selected = "";
          }

          }
         </script>
          <script language="javascript">
              function check(elem) {
        document.getElementById('dis').disabled = !elem.selectedIndex;
          }
          </script>
          <?php
               mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
           mysql_select_db("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

          if($_POST['course_code']){
      @$exam_name=$_POST['course_code'];
          ?>

         <B>SELECT COURSE CODE</B> <select name="hai2" id="hai2">
            <option>Select</option>
            <?php

        $query="SELECT distinct course_code FROM examcourse where exam_name = '$exam_name' ";

             $result = mysql_query($query);
          while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<option value='".$nt['course_code']."'>".$nt['course_code']."</option>";
                 }
                  ?>

                </select>
                 <?php }
              if($_POST['subject_code']){
              @$subject_code=$_POST['subject_code'];
            ?>
             <B>SELECT SUBJECT CODE</B>
           <select name="hai3[]"  id="hai3" multiple="multiple" onChange="changeSelection(this.value),check(this);">
    <option value="0">Select All</option>
     <?php

        $query="SELECT distinct subject_code FROM coursesubject where course_code = '".$subject_code."' ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$nt['subject_code']."'>".$nt['subject_code']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
       </select>

          <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `isset` like

```
if(isset($_POST['course_code'])){
     $exam_name=$_POST['course_code'];
}
```

And

```
if(isset($_POST['subject_code'])){
     $subject_code=$_POST['subject_code'];
}
```

Comment: Remove the error suppression (`@`) and you will get an upvote ;)

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt notice them...Thanks @SverriM.Olsen for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a key (in this case the key 'course_code') exists in an array by this syntax:
    `array_key_exists($key, $array);`

In your case this would be:

```
if(array_key_exists('course_code', $_POST){
    @$exam_name=$_POST['course_code'];
}
```